# Encrypted Cloudfront script getting injected to our site and causing js errors in our logs

Tags: javascript, encryption, cryptography, xss

A javascript error started popping up in our logs and exploded into tens of thousands of errors over a short period - probably 2-3 ours - then disappeared.  The original of the error was traced back to this cryptic javascript file: https://d1ui18tz1fx59z.cloudfront.net/js/all/pd2.js?v=17.  A similar error popped up again yesterday for another 2-3 hours, same file, but a new version parameter: https://d1ui18tz1fx59z.cloudfront.net/js/all/pd2.js?v=18.

Anyone have any clue what this file is or how to decode it?  Is is a possible XSS attack?  How is it throwing errors inside our js stack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just saw this on a site that I manage.

The script is encoded but it's fairly easy to find out what it expands to:

```
$ curl https://d1ui18tz1fx59z.cloudfront.net/js/all/pd2.js?v=18 > raw.js
$ sed -i 's/eval/console.log/' raw.js
$ node raw.js
[lots of output]
```

I then fed the output into http://jsbeautifier.org/ and got https://gist.github.com/jonleighton/562da353853cd7f2e701.

It definitely looks like some sort of script to display ads. My guess is that a user browsing a website on an infected computed gets this script injected into pages that they view. But I don't really know and there aren't many clues in the expanded script.

Comment: Thanks Jon - that is pretty interesting that all that javascript can come from that input file.  I appriciate you sharing the gist!